# Existence of a non-zero T- invariant subspace on $\mathbb{Q}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

For any linear transformation $T:\mathbb{Q}^{4} \to \mathbb{Q}^{4} $, does there always exist a non-zero T- invariant subspace?

---

As we know

For any linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{4}$, there exists a non-zero T- invariant subspace.

Does completeness property cause some differences for T- invariant subspaces?

Answer (score 3):

Take any $4 \times 4$ matrix of rational numbers whose characteristic polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, and form a linear operator $T$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ based on this matrix. If $V \le \Bbb{Q}^4$ is some proper non-trivial invariant subspace of $T$, then $T|_V$ is an operator on $V$, whose characteristic polynomial has degree $0 < \dim(V) < 4$, and which divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$. But, this can't happen, as the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is irreducible.